# Android: resize an HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, resize, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to resize at runtime a simple HorizontalScrollView that contains only a Linearlayout this way:

```
HorizontalScrollView h = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview_row_1);
h.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));
```

but then i get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(5098): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

How should I resize my scrollView properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because the HorizontalScrollView is not inside a FrameLayout.
the layout params have to match the root view of your HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Yes my HorizontalScrollView is inside a LinearLayout, going to try with the FrameLayout as you suggested.

Comment: if it's inside a LinearLayout you have to use the LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: Yes, I used LinearLayout.LayoutParams and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To be more generic, you can probably just use a ViewGroup.LayoutParams... (so that even if you changed the LinearLayout in the future, you won't have to change that code)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
HorizontalScrollView h = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview_row_1);
h.setLayoutParams(new HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams(50,50));
```